# Custom HTML input component

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a new html component using javascript and CSS.
The new component is exactly like `TextField (<input type="text">)`.

The additional behaviour is each character in the TextField is separated in a box.

Is there any existing component available ? If not please give some ideas how to design this component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing exists in HTML for a multiple text input like you've described.

You'll need to build it yourself using multiple `<input type="text"/>` elements.

```
TextField(<input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/>...)
```

Just out of interest though, why do you want this control?  Typically this kind of field is horrible from a usability standpoint (even if you hook in event handlers to auto-tab you from one box to the next)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to *look* like the characters are in boxes, you might be able to use a fixed-width font and a clever background graphic. Admittedly, this could pose some interesting internationalization challenges.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a series of input boxes with a character limit of 1 and use CSS to make them 'square-like' to accomodate just one character